# Can we always choose a uniformizer which generates the function field extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic 0, and let $f : Y\rightarrow X$ be a finite map of smooth curves over $k$.

Let $x\in X$ be a $k$-rational point, and let $y\in f^{-1}(x)$ have local ring $B$, which is a discrete valuation ring. Must there exist a uniformizer $\pi\in B$ such that $k(Y) = k(X)(\pi)$?

Comment: what do you mean with "$k(X)$ is algebraically closed inside $k(Y)$" ?

Comment: The only time you have this situation is when $f$ is an open immersion.

Comment: @Mohan Hm perhaps I was unclear. I mean that $\pi$ is a uniformizer of $B$, not $A$. For example, if $Y\rightarrow X$ is totally ramified above $x$, then any uniformizer will generate the function field extension.

Comment: @mercio Sorry, I meant that $k$ is algebraically closed inside $k(Y)$, which I suppose is extraneous. I've removed it.